# write data from serial port to printer

Tags: linux, printing, serial-port

I currently am running a command in tty1 on Ubuntu 10.04 to print SMDR data from my phone system.  Problem is that the phone system automatically adds a CR and LF (I think) in to the end of the data it sends.

The output should look like this

> Data line 1 
>   Data line 2 
>  Data line 3 
>  etc.

It instead looks like this

> Data line 1
>
> Data line 2
>
> Data line 3
>
> etc.

I don't want the print to do this.  I currently have the command `cat /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/lp0` running

Is there a command that can stop this from happening ?
Essentially, I want to continually echo ttyS0 to lp0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `tr`:

```
cat file_1 | tr -d "\r" > file_2
```